# Creating Contracts via

Tags: solidity, contract-development

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html#creating-contracts-via-new

Is it possible to create a custom new contract by using this? Like, could we pass some data in a transaction which includes the details/code of the new contract, instead of having the code to be previously written in the contract?